# Description of Puzzle Type

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I am looking for the name of a certain type of word puzzle.  A string of letters is given without any spaces between those letters.  By strategically inserting spaces into the string, different valid phrases are generated.

I would use Google for this, but Google is tough if you don't know the search phrase.

Comment: This is probably more suited to the _Puzzling_ SE site.

Comment: I think Rebus is what you're looking for. While the main form of rebus is using pictorial clues, there's also letter based rebus puzzles. Here's what wikipedia has to say about Rebus:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus

Comment: Gary's Student - Wow, you deleted that other question about words ending in _s_ mighty quickly. I'm sure there are at least a handful of novel examples, like _his_ and _hiss_, _axe_ (the tool) and _axes_ (the plural of axis), _passe_ and _passes_, _crosse_ and _crosses_, etc. If you need more, it's really a matter of looking for letter/syllable patterns that might yield one.

Comment: @J.R.  Thanks for the help!!!  I did not want to anger the forum police; I am not a smooth criminal.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I should have said, "If you need more, start with _more_." ;^)

Comment: @J.R.  ***SUPREMELY CLEVER!***